# Filtering out rows that don't meet specific order and value criteria in Python or tSQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, t-sql

I need some help filtering rows out of a customer dataset I've created.

The dataset contains customer IDs, policy numbers, and the dates related to their policies. Customers can switch freely between policies, anytime they wish. The following dataset is all just an example dataset I put together. I can use either pandas or sql server to filter out the right customers.

#### Objective:

I want to filter the dataset and retrieve customers under the following conditions:

- Customer must have chronologically been on Policy rate **13**, then switched to **11**.
- Customers must have **atleast** 350 days on both policies.

I've included a column (policy_order) showing the order active policies. It doesn't matter when the 13 => 11 switch occurred, as long as the jump was from 13 to 11, and they spent 350 days on each.

```
| row | cust_id | policy_num | policy_start | policy_end | policy_order | days_on_policy |
|-----|---------|------------|--------------|------------|--------------|----------------|
| 1   | 1000    | 17         | 09/23/2013   | 11/05/2013 | 1            | 43             |
| 2   | 1200    | 13         | 08/26/2011   | 04/30/2019 | 1            | 2804           |
| 3   | 3400    | 13         | 08/31/2012   | 02/22/2015 | 1            | 905            |
| 4   | 5000    | 17         | 04/12/2014   | 07/28/2014 | 1            | 107            |
| 5   | 5000    | 13         | 07/28/2014   | 08/24/2016 | 2            | 758            |
| 6   | 5000    | 11         | 08/24/2016   | 10/20/2018 | 3            | 787            |
| 7   | 5000    | 13         | 10/20/2018   | 05/02/2019 | 4            | 194            |
| 8   | 7600    | 13         | 02/02/2015   | 05/03/2019 | 1            | 1551           |
| 9   | 4300    | 11         | 01/07/2015   | 05/04/2017 | 1            | 848            |
| 10  | 4300    | 13         | 05/04/2017   | 05/05/2019 | 2            | 731            |
| 11  | 9800    | 13         | 12/12/2001   | 10/06/2015 | 1            | 5046           |
| 12  | 9800    | 11         | 10/06/2015   | 05/06/2019 | 2            | 1308           |
```

As seen in the table above, two customers match the criteria. Customer 5000, and customer 9800. I used customer 5000 as an example, because they've switched policies multiple times but still meet the criteria in rows 5 and 6. These are the only rows I'm concerned with.

So the output that I would want to see would look like this:

```
| row | acct | policy_num | policy_start | policy_end | policy_order | days_on_policy |
|-----|------|------------|--------------|------------|--------------|----------------|
| 1   | 5000 | 13         | 7/28/2014    | 8/24/2016  | 2            | 758            |
| 2   | 5000 | 11         | 8/24/2016    | 10/20/2018 | 3            | 787            |
| 3   | 9800 | 13         | 12/12/2001   | 10/6/2015  | 1            | 5046           |
| 4   | 9800 | 11         | 10/6/2015    | 5/6/2019   | 2            | 1308           |
```

The results would show the customer ID, the correct policy numbers, relevant dates, and how many days they were on each policy.

I've tried filtering using the WHERE clause in SQL (which I'm admittedly bad at), but haven't even come close to an answer - and don't even really know where to start.

My main goal is to try and get the rows filtered using order, policy number, and days on policy.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution based on *Pandas*, then define the following
filtering function:

```
def fltr(gr):
    wrk = gr.query('policy_num in [11, 13]').sort_values(['policy_order'])
    pNum = wrk.set_index('policy_order').policy_num
    if ~((pNum == 11).any() and (pNum == 13).any()):
        return None
    ind11 = pNum[pNum == 11].index[0]
    ind13 = pNum[pNum == 13].index[0]
    if ind13 > ind11:
        return None
    if (wrk.groupby('policy_num').days_on_policy.sum() >= 350).all():
        return wrk.drop_duplicates(subset='policy_num')
    return None
```

Then use it in *groupby*:

```
df.groupby('cust_id').apply(fltr)
```

**A short description of the filtering function**

It starts with computing auxiliary variables:

- *wrk* - rows of the current group for *policy_num* == either *11*
  or *13*, ordered by *policy_order*.
- *pNum* - *policy_num* column from *wrk*, indexed by *policy_order*.

The filtering function has 2 "initial" occasions to return the empty content
(*None*), to **reject** the current group:

1. *pNum* failed to contain at least one *11* and at least one *13*.
2. The index (actually *policy_order*) of the first *13* element in *pNum*
   is greater than the index of the first *11* element (policy *13*
   **follows** policy *11*).

The last decision is based on a question: Does each of the policies
in question (*11* and *13*) have the sum of *days_on_policy* >= 350?
If yes, the function returns rows from *wrk* without repetitions,
to drop possible last *13* (as in the case of group *5000*).

Otherwise, the current group is also rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I guess you would need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM policy p1
WHERE policy_num = 13 
AND days_on_policy >= 350
AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM policy p2 
   WHERE p1.cust_id = p2.cust_id
     AND p2.policy_num =11
     AND p2.policy_start >= p1.policy_end
     AND p2.days_on_policy >= 350)
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM policy p1
where policy_num = 11
AND days_on_policy >= 350
AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM policy p2 
   WHERE p1.cust_id = p2.cust_id
     AND p2.policy_num =13
     AND p1.policy_start >= p2.policy_end
     AND p2.days_on_policy >= 350)
```

[SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2d644/4)

Answer (score 0):

With a self join and the conditions applied on the ON clause:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on 
  t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id 
  and (
    (t2.policy_start = t1.policy_end) and (t1.policy_num = 13 and t2.policy_num = 11)
    or
    (t1.policy_start = t2.policy_end) and (t2.policy_num = 13 and t1.policy_num = 11)
  ) 
  and t1.days_on_policy  >= 350 and t2.days_on_policy >= 350
  order by t1.cust_id, t1.policy_start
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96b1bce6613f18c4c5fd99b7e7b827dd).
Results:

```
> row | cust_id | policy_num | policy_start        | policy_end          | policy_order | days_on_policy
> --: | ------: | ---------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----------: | -------------:
>   5 |    5000 |         13 | 28/07/2014 00:00:00 | 24/08/2016 00:00:00 |            2 |            758
>   6 |    5000 |         11 | 24/08/2016 00:00:00 | 20/10/2018 00:00:00 |            3 |            787
>  11 |    9800 |         13 | 12/12/2001 00:00:00 | 06/10/2015 00:00:00 |            1 |           5046
>  12 |    9800 |         11 | 06/10/2015 00:00:00 | 06/05/2019 00:00:00 |            2 |           1308
```

Comment: I take "and they spent 350 days on each" to mean `days_on_policy >= 350` for _each separate_ policy rather than the sum (`t1.days_on_policy + t2.days_on_policy >= 350`). ("Customers must have **at least** 350 days on both policies." is open to misinterpretation.) Perhaps the OP will clarify.

Comment: @HABO I think you are right and I missed it. Thanks. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly always better to do the filtering of data within the query, unless performance of the database is affected by the query.

If your dataset isn't to large this is the procedure I would use to filter.

```py
#filter on the criteria for the policy number 
df_13_fltr = df[(df['policy_num']==13)&\
                (df['days_on_policy']>=350)][['row','cust_id','policy_end']]
df_11_fltr = df[(df['policy_num']==11)&\
                (df['days_on_policy']>=350)][['row','cust_id','policy_start']]

#merge the 2 filtered DataFrames together and compare the policy_end and policy_start
df_fltr = df_11_fltr.merge(df_13_fltr, on='cust_id',how='inner',suffixes=('13','11'))
df_fltr =df_fltr[df_fltr['policy_end']<=df_fltr['policy_start']][['row13','row11']]

#put the rows in a list
rows = list(df_fltr['row13'].values)+list(df_fltr['row11'])

#using the rows list in a lambda filter on the original dataset
df[df['row'].apply(lambda x: x in rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a groupby on cust_id and a rolling window to look back on the policy_num to find 11 current and 13 previous.  I originally thought to create a filter on 350 days but commented it out because it could break the sequence of policy_num

```
 data = """
 | row | cust_id | policy_num | policy_start | policy_end | policy_order |      days_on_policy |
 | 1   | 1000    | 17         | 09/23/2013   | 11/05/2013 | 1            | 43                  |
 | 2   | 1200    | 13         | 08/26/2011   | 04/30/2019 | 1            | 2804                |
 | 3   | 3400    | 13         | 08/31/2012   | 02/22/2015 | 1            | 905                 |
 | 4   | 5000    | 17         | 04/12/2014   | 07/28/2014 | 1            | 107                 |
 | 5   | 5000    | 13         | 07/28/2014   | 08/24/2016 | 2            | 758                 |
 | 6   | 5000    | 11         | 08/24/2016   | 10/20/2018 | 3            | 787                 |
 | 7   | 5000    | 13         | 10/20/2018   | 05/02/2019 | 4            | 194                 |
 | 8   | 7600    | 13         | 02/02/2015   | 05/03/2019 | 1            | 1551           |
 | 9   | 4300    | 11         | 01/07/2015   | 05/04/2017 | 1            | 848                 |
 | 10  | 4300    | 13         | 05/04/2017   | 05/05/2019 | 2            | 731                 |
 | 11  | 9800    | 13         | 12/12/2001   | 10/06/2015 | 1            | 5046           |
 | 12  | 9800    | 11         | 10/06/2015   | 05/06/2019 | 2            | 1308           |
```

"""

```
 data = data.strip().split('\n')
 data = [i.strip().split('|') for i in data]
 data = [i[1:-1] for i in data]
 columns=[data.strip() for data in data[0]]

 df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=columns)
 print(df.columns)
 df.set_index(['row'],inplace=True)
 # set the datatypes for each column
 df['cust_id'] = df['cust_id'].astype(int)
 df['policy_num'] = df['policy_num'].astype(int)
 df['policy_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['policy_start'])
 df['policy_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['policy_end'])
 df['policy_order'] = df['policy_order'].astype(int)
 df['days_on_policy'] = df['days_on_policy'].astype(int)
 #print(df)

 def create_filter(df, filter_cols, filter_values,operator_values):
     filter_list = []
     for col, val,operator in zip(filter_cols, filter_values,operator_values):
         if operator=='>':
             filter_list.append(df[col] > val)
         elif operator=='>=':
             filter_list.append(df[col] >= val)
         elif operator=='<':
             filter_list.append(df[col] < val)
         elif operator=='<=':
             filter_list.append(df[col] <= val)
         elif operator=='==':
             filter_list.append(df[col] == val)
     return pd.concat(filter_list, axis=1).all(axis=1)
 
 #filter_cols=['days_on_policy']
 #filter_values=[350]
 #operator_values=['>']
 #filter=create_filter(df, filter_cols, filter_values,operator_values)
 #df=df[filter]

 df = df.sort_values(by=['cust_id','policy_order'], ascending=False)
 #print(df)

 df_grouped = df.groupby('cust_id')
 rolling_df=df_grouped.rolling(window=1).sum()
 prev_key,prev_policy_num,prev_days_on_policy=tuple(),"",""
 prev_key=None
 for key,item in rolling_df.iterrows():
     policy_num=item['policy_num']
     days_on_policy=item['days_on_policy']
     if prev_key!=None:
         prev_policy_num,prev_days_on_policy=rolling_df.loc[prev_key]     [['policy_num','days_on_policy']]
         if key[0]==prev_key[0] and policy_num==13 and prev_policy_num==11 and prev_days_on_policy>350 and days_on_policy>350:
        print(prev_key[0],prev_policy_num)
     prev_key=key
```

output:

```
5000 11.0
9800 11.0
```